# Where does Mesa store its Vulkan shader cache on Linux?

Tags: cache, mesa

I would like to delete the Mesa Vulkan shader cache for a particular application I'm using. Where is this cache stored by default on recent (Mesa 19/20) versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
rm -rf ~/.cache/mesa_shader_cache
```

More on it here: https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html